# Why some TV shows like morning shows have no ending credits?

Tags: production, credits, crew

I've been watching some morning shows like *Good Morning America*, *Today* and *This Morning* (USA) and noticed that none of them have crew ending credits, just opening credits with the anchors and daily guests. Is there a reason for that? Is it because they are considered a newscast and thereby they do not follow guilds' guidelines such as WGA and DGA?

Comment: Downvoters care to comment?  This seems like a reasonable, TV-oriented question to me.  I certainly don't know the answer and might be interested to learn it.

Comment: Whether they are "news" in the journalistic sense, they are definitely not scripted fiction. While I don't watch morning talk shows, I have seen a few in the past, and I wonder if there might be some credits hidden in there somewhere, at least for some of them.

Comment: The same is sometimes true of sports coverage.  I have no way to document or "back this up" - but I've personally noticed that news and sports will occasionally show ending credits.  I believe some news organizations may do this on certain holidays - though they may air in a different day segment than the morning show (air for news division as a whole).  An example in sports would be when the recent NFL season ended (or at least NBC's coverage ended); NBC ran lengthy credits identifying nearly everyone at NBC Sports.

Comment: Sometimes the US network news programs run credits once a week, or extended versions of the credits once a month or once a year.   I believe the CBS evening news used to run longer credits on Friday night.  I recall one of the network news programs signing off at the end of the year with the anchor saying “... now let’s show you a list of all the people who worked on this program in the last year,” or something like that…

Answer (score 1):

### Probably time-constraints

An article on NewscastStudio.com, *[Networks celebrate the holidays by paying tribute to their teams](https://www.newscaststudio.com/2019/12/27/am-network-morning-shows-full-credits-2019/)*, gives a brief explanation about end-credits:

> Some newscasts, stations and networks opt to run full credits New Year’s Eve or New Year’s Day.
>
> **Other newscasts will run full credits throughout the year either as time allows or on a predetermined frequency, such as once a week**, though these are obviously without the holiday theme.